# Add method on a list of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Ok guys, object developer newbie here. I try to do an animation of falling cube as explain here : [Falling animation to fill a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768826/falling-animation-to-fill-a-webpage)

I have some algorithmic issues. I follow the model of a tetris game but I want multiple pixels falling at the same time. So I have a constructor with some methods to move my pixel.

But now I use my constructor to create an array of object like :

```
var a_player = [];

function addPlayer(pos){
  var player = new Player(pos);
  a_player.push(player);
}

addPlayer({x: 3, y: 3});
addPlayer({x: 0, y: 0});
```

And I want to use some public methods like a collide() method :

```
function collide(arena, player) {
  const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos];
  for (let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
    for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x) {
      if (m[y][x] !== 00 &&
          (arena[y + o.y] &&
          arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
            return true;
          }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

But I don't know what's the best way to do it. I can use a "for" like

```
for (i = 0; i < a_player.length; i++){
            console.log(a_player[i].pos);
}
```

but I have to apply it on all my methods, or I can duplicate my method by the number of player I have in my array (but in the ends I want more than 20k players...). So can you help me with that kind of problematic ?

Comment: 20k players...? Is this Node.js or something?

Comment: You could use `Array.prototype.forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Do you think it's a bad idea using only Canvas and JS to do the thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for:

```
 function collide(arena) {
  const [m, o] = [this.matrix, this.pos];
  for (let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
    for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x) {
      if (m[y][x] !== 00 &&
          (arena[y + o.y] &&
          arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
            return true;
          }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
Player.prototype.collide=collide;

for (i = 0; i < a_player.length; i++){
           a_player[i].collide(arena)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it looks like it work. The thing is, I actually don't have any error left, but my animation won't work ... I don't know if the best is to update my post or create a new one ?

Comment: I think you should open a new one that talks specifically about the animation side.